# Use Run Configuration for IntelliJ File Watcher

Tags: intellij-idea, build, webstorm

I Just wanted to know really quickly why the IntelliJ File Watchers take command line programs rather than allowing me to use the Run Configurations?

I have my build chain nicely configured through the run configurations and I want to use the File Watchers to rerun certain parts of it when I modify certain source files.

Note that I could achieve this using Grunt which I already am using for this project, but I'd like to try using the file watchers.

Anyone know why this is so and how I can work around this?

Thanks

Comment: File Watcher is just an advanced version of External Tools that targets specific needs. What it does -- it runs specified external command once watched file gets modified/saved in IDE. Once tool is finished running, IDE will check specified paths/files ("Output path to refresh" field) to check those files for modifications (reload from disk).

Comment: If you already have grunt/gulp/etd tasks for your project -- you can call them using File Watcher: program -> grunt/gulp/etc executable; params -> the rest of the command.

Comment: In that case the same question still applies

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to delete that comment, ignore it pls.

Comment: So they are inherently different and incompatible, is that right?

Comment: File Watcher calls **external app**; it cannot use your existing Run/Debug Configuration unfortunately; it cannot call your IDE-integrated gulp/grunt/npm task as well, but you can call it as an external app, no issues here.

Comment: See if Save Actions plugin may be of any help here (it's not the same as it works with files saved in IDE only) and may still not be able to use Run/Debug Configurations .. but worth checking anyway (Not using it myself so cannot say what exact functionality it can offer here, but it has some handy options anyway).

Comment: P.S. To delete your own comment -- just hover over it and the "Delete" link will be at the end of the comment.

Comment: Is there some documentation on IDE Scripting that might help? I haven't seemed to be able to find anything.

Comment: Regarding deleting comments, I'm on mobile and don't have access to a desktop at the moment

Comment: Sorry, no solid ideas on IDE Scripting part from my end. IDE supports Groovy script (used in Live Templates / DB Export etc) ... but I'm not sure if it's available in WebStorm outside of those tools. IDEA: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ide-scripting-console.html PhpStorm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-scripting-console.html No such link for WebStorm though

Comment: Okay, I'll do some further research and I'll let you know how I go. Thanks for your help.